# Check email send volume automation vs Manual

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting

I want to create a report to see the volume of the emails through the automations and manual/Ad-hoc for 2022. The only way I can think of to get the data is through Reports but I will have to manually select all the Journey names and we have a lot. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: If you’re looking for info on jb vs other sends, you could join the sent data view with jb activity data view